# Shader gives wrong pixel color on Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, shader

I have a simple fragment shader:

```
varying vec2 v_texCoord;    
void main() {
  nx=v_texCoord.x;
  ny=v_texCoord.y;
  if(nx < 0.5){ r=1.0;g=0.0;b=0.0;}
  if(nx >= 0.5) {r=0.0;g=0.0;b=1.0;}
  gl_FragColor = vec4(r,g,b,1.0);
}
```

Work as expected, but if I take a screenshot and open it in image editor I see that most red pixels are (255,0,0), but pixels bordering with blue pixels are (247,0,8). I'm wondering what is the reason and could it be fixed somehow?

[image]

Comment: Which format is the screenshot saved in? It may be an image compression artifact.

Comment: It's PNG. Screenshot is made by DDMS tool from Android SDK.

Comment: It is really something wrong with screenshot, glReadPixels gives correct pixels. Thank you samgak for idea!